# Unpacking values from list in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

Python Newbie here:
Given a list and a value, how can I unpack the list into separate objects and prepend a value.  Length of the array isn't known, unlike in code below:

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = 0,x
y
```

Current Output:

```
(0, [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Desired Output:

```
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I know it can be done easily in Python 3 using `y = 0,*x` but how can it be done in Python 2.7?

Thanks

Comment: Does the result _need_ to be a tuple, or is a list ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use unpacking here, but just concatenation.

```
y = [0] + x
```

Comment: and if @berneng wants y to be tuple he can simply do y = tuple([0] + x) or y = tuple(y).

Answer (score 2):

Insert y into x and make x Tuple

```
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = 0
x.insert(0,y)
print(tuple(x))
```

**output**

```
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Note, this modifies `x`, which OP may not want.

Comment: Why are you modifying `x`? Besides, inserting at position zero is relatively expensive, since all subsequent list items have to be moved up to make room, which is an O(n) operation, and although it happens at C speed it's better to avoid it if it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You **could** do it with parameter unpacking.

```
>>> (lambda *a: a)(0, *x)
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

But don't.